# Deploy failed for bingoquimico - Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Tags: deployment, netlify, building

https://bingoquimico.netlify.app/ **(I am trying to update it just to learn how to deploy using vite, I added a favicon and added a folder as src).**

**The repository is:** https://github.com/cesarnuness/BingoAlice

**The build settings are**: https://global.discourse-cdn.com/netlify/original/3X/b/1/b1a159729142c6ca3fbb81bc40cbc78d0a779736.png

```
6:14:25 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
6:14:23 PM: Netlify Build                                                 
6:14:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: ❯ Version
6:14:23 PM:   @netlify/build 29.17.1
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: ❯ Flags
6:14:23 PM:   baseRelDir: true
6:14:23 PM:   buildId: 64bc46a22d72f500089748f9
6:14:23 PM:   deployId: 64bc46a22d72f500089748fb
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: ❯ Current directory
6:14:23 PM:   /opt/build/repo
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: ❯ Config file
6:14:23 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: ❯ Context
6:14:23 PM:   production
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: Build command from Netlify app                                
6:14:23 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: $ npm run build
6:14:23 PM: > bingo-quimico@0.0.0 build
6:14:23 PM: > vite build
6:14:23 PM: vite v4.4.6 building for production...
6:14:23 PM: transforming...
6:14:23 PM: ✓ 4 modules transformed.
6:14:23 PM: rendering chunks...
6:14:23 PM: computing gzip size...
6:14:23 PM: dist/index.html                  9.34 kB │ gzip: 2.99 kB
6:14:23 PM: dist/assets/Logo-3f82143e.png   55.94 kB
6:14:23 PM: dist/assets/index-a7e7811d.css   3.00 kB │ gzip: 0.96 kB
6:14:23 PM: dist/assets/index-bc689140.js    4.24 kB │ gzip: 2.11 kB
6:14:23 PM: ✓ built in 123ms
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:23 PM: (build.command completed in 534ms)
6:14:23 PM: ​
6:14:25 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:14:25 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:14:25 PM: Finished processing build request in 11.19s
```

I tried to update the website which was plain html, css and javascript to use Vite as a bundler (just as a learning process while I was updating the name of the website and the favicon. But it just didn't work. I tried using chatGPT before and after but it seems that it's just a very generic error, which there are thousands of possibilities to cause it.